# VS Code IntelliSense fails on C# 9.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, c#-9.0

It's been a quite a while that C# 9 has been around and now I just noticed that SDK 5 has officially been released. For that reason I switched to C# 9 and .Net 5 but 'ms-dotnettools.csharp' which is the official VS Code extension for C# unfortunately does not have syntax highlighting and appropriate IntelliSense support for C# 9. For example it doesn't highlight `record` types, or when I use Top-Level Statements, it confuses that with a compile time error. However, the project always compiles.

Is there any workaround to fix these and enjoy the amazing C# 9.0 when coding in VS Code?

Comment: The team responsible for the extension is aware of this issue. See [this issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4211) on GitHub.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been addressed with the latest release of the C# extension (v1.23.9). In order to enable, add the following to your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
"csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
```

[Relevant Issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4308) | [Relevant Pull Request](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/2049)

Comment: Great answer J, I will give it a try. Keep on the great work.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Oh, I didn't really do any work - to be quite honest the issue was driving me bonkers, and when I noticed the fix was in, I just wanted to find out how to make it work! Cheers!

Answer (score -8):

I use ReSharper instead in this problem

Comment: I don't think it would be compatible with vs code but even if that would be, ReSharper is a nightmare, Rider is also a much worse nightmare.